# Adding a filter to MongoDB query increases the time taken for count()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection called `listings` with more than 5 million documents and indexes (relevant only) with keys:
`{"_id": 1}`
`{"dated": 1}`
`{"causelist_type": 1}`

I am trying to run the query

```
db.listings.count({
    dated: {
        $in: [ISODate("2018-02-17T00:00:00Z"), ISODate("2018-02-16T00:00:00Z"),ISODate("2018-02-10T00:00:00Z")]
    },
    causelist_type: {$ne: -1}
})
```

It is taking 130s. (Recorded by prepending and appending the command with `print(new Date())`)

But if I remove the filter `causelist_type: {$ne: -1}`, the query runs almost instantaneously (~1s).

`explain().queryPlanner` for the query with `causelist_type` clause:

```
{
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "kl.listings",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [
            {
                "dated" : {
                    "$in" : [
                        ISODate("2018-02-10T00:00:00Z"),
                        ISODate("2018-02-16T00:00:00Z"),
                        ISODate("2018-02-17T00:00:00Z")
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "$nor" : [{
                    "causelist_type" : {
                        "$eq" : -1
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
            "$nor" : [{
                "causelist_type" : {
                    "$eq" : -1
                }
            }]
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                    "dated" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "dated_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 1,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "dated" : [
                    "[new Date(1518220800000), new Date(1518220800000)]",
                    "[new Date(1518739200000), new Date(1518739200000)]",
                    "[new Date(1518825600000), new Date(1518825600000)]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [{
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
                "dated" : {
                        "$in" : [
                                ISODate("2018-02-10T00:00:00Z"),
                                ISODate("2018-02-16T00:00:00Z"),
                                ISODate("2018-02-17T00:00:00Z")
                        ]
                }
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                    "causelist_type" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "causelist_type_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 1,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "causelist_type" : [
                    "[MinKey, -1.0)",
                    "(-1.0, MaxKey]"
                ]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

`explain().queryPlanner` for the query **without** `causelist_type` clause:

```
{
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "kl.listings",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "dated" : {
            "$in" : [
                ISODate("2018-02-10T00:00:00Z"),
                ISODate("2018-02-16T00:00:00Z"),
                ISODate("2018-02-17T00:00:00Z")
            ]
        }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "COUNT",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "dated" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "dated_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 1,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
            "dated" : [
                    "[new Date(1518220800000), new Date(1518220800000)]",
                    "[new Date(1518739200000), new Date(1518739200000)]",
                    "[new Date(1518825600000), new Date(1518825600000)]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
}
```

I am using MongoDB 3.6.2.

What I don't understand is how can adding a 'filter' increase the query time so much when same index is being used in the queries with and without the 'filter'.
Let me know if you need any more information.

EDIT:
I also tried modifying the `causelist_type` clause to `causelist_type: {$eq: -1}` and the query runs instantaneously. Please explain.

EDIT 2:
`explain().queryPlanner` for the query with `causelist_type: {$eq: -1}` clause:

```
{
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "kl.listings",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [{
            "causelist_type" : {
                "$eq" : -1
            }
        },
        {
            "dated" : {
                "$in" : [
                    ISODate("2018-02-10T00:00:00Z"),
                    ISODate("2018-02-16T00:00:00Z"),
                    ISODate("2018-02-17T00:00:00Z")
                ]
            }
        }]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
            "causelist_type" : {
                "$eq" : -1
            }
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                    "dated" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "dated_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 1,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "dated" : [
                    "[new Date(1518220800000), new Date(1518220800000)]",
                    "[new Date(1518739200000), new Date(1518739200000)]",
                    "[new Date(1518825600000), new Date(1518825600000)]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [{
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
            "dated" : {
                "$in" : [
                    ISODate("2018-02-10T00:00:00Z"),
                    ISODate("2018-02-16T00:00:00Z"),
                    ISODate("2018-02-17T00:00:00Z")
                ]
            }
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "causelist_type" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "causelist_type_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 1,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "causelist_type" : [
                    "[-1.0, -1.0]"
                ]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Also when I change the `causelist_type` clause to `causelist_type: {$nin: [-1, -2]}`, it is **fast** and uses the same indexes and input stage as `causelist_type: {$eq: -1}`, just a different filter.

And none of them them are using index intersection, as [explain results documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#explain-output-index-intersection) says that we should se `"stage" : "AND_SORTED"` in cases where index intersection is used.

Comment: Have you tried adding a compound index `{ "dated": 1, "causelist_type": 1 }`?

Comment: @chridam No I did not. The collection already has a lot of indexes. Moreover why isn't it not picking up the existing index on `causelist_type`. I thought MongoDB can use two indexes (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071).

Comment: Try with `db.listings.count({ dated: ... , $hint: { "dated" : 1 }})`, and let me know how is the execution time.

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla I don't think `$hint` works with count(). The query you said returned `unknown top level operator: $query` and when I tried appending `.hint()` to the query it said: `db.listings.count(...).hint is not a function`

Comment: Accorded to the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) it shoud work. It was introduced in version 2.6.

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla I think it works only with cursor requests. Because even to get `explain()` to work with `count()` you have to prepend it like `db.collection.explain().count`. As there is no `db.collection.hint()`, I am assuming you can only use `hint` with `find()` and the likes.

Comment: `db.item.explain().count({}, { $hint: {"_id" : 1} })` This is working for me in 3.2.18.

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla Ok. I was adding `$hint` to the first object. My bad. But anyways, `db.listings.count({dated: ..., causelist_type: ...}, {$hint: {dated: 1}})` took ~150s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the `causelist_type` term in the query, the count query is fully covered by the index on `dated`, which makes it very fast.

Note the `"stage" : "COUNT"` in the winning plan for this case.

Adding the `causelist_type` to the query requires that every document satisfying the `dated` part of the query to be read from disk so that its `causelist_type` value can be checked to see if it's `$ne: -1`.

Note the `"stage" : "FETCH"` in the winning plan for this case.

As for why index intersection isn't being used here with the `causelist_type` index, that's likely because you're using a `$ne` query which makes the index much less efficient than a match (as you found when testing with `$eq` instead).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It does explain why the query without `causelist_type` term is blazing fast. But it still doesn't explain why index intersection is not being used. Can you please take a look at my recent edits?